# copy/select text in WhatsThis

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

***Example***:

```
class tab_1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(tab_1, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
 def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("tab1")
        self.btn.setWhatsThis(
            """''(parameter) self: ~tab
                Sourcery Code Metrics
                Complexity  0   ⭐
                Size    108 
                Working Memory  4   ⭐
                Quality Score   82 % ⭐
                ⟠  self: [tab]    Docc"""
            ""
        )
```

I use the `setWhatsThis` and try to **copy**/**select** the text of it, but
when I click the mouse

In `WhatsThis` area is **Disappear**!

Example

[image]

Comment: That's not a "problem in pyqt" (which is a binding, so the problem would actually be with Qt, not PyQt). That's the behavior of *any* tooltip on *any* OS. They are not intended to be interacted with (and they should ***not***). That said, if you're asking us how to do it, you won't receive any answer here, as that's not the scope of StackOverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: your question already has the `pyqt` tag, please don't edit the title by adding it as it's unnecessary.

Comment: @musicamente. I agree that it's not a problem in PyQt. In fact the [QWhatsThis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwhatsthis.html) class is working exactly as advertised. However, I think this is an interesting question because maybe there is some clever workaround or subclassing that would allow a select or copy operation.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the what's this behavior is to only handles clicks on hyperlinks (which normally launch the application help dialog), so if the user clicks it, it will automatically close anyway.

The only solution is to override the default behavior by mimicking what Qt normally does: install an event filter on the application whenever a top level window receives a `EnterWhatsThisMode` event type, and create a custom widget that is shown whenever it's appropriate.

Since this will cause to override *all* what's this cases, I'd suggest to also set the `WA_CustomWhatsThis` attribute for the widgets that will have selectable text, so that you can use the standard behavior for any other case.

The custom widget is actually a QLabel with the `Popup` window flag set, which will make the widget a top level window that also captures mouse events, and with the `TextSelectableByMouse` and `LinksAccessibleByMouse` text interaction flags set.

```
class SelectableWhatsThis(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent, pos):
        super().__init__(parent.whatsThis(), parent, flags=QtCore.Qt.Popup)
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(
            QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse | QtCore.Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse)

        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase)
        self.setForegroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.setContentsMargins(12, 8, 12, 8)
        self.move(pos)
        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.pos() not in self.rect():
            self.close()
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        self.close()


class WhatsThisHelper(QtCore.QObject):
    installed = active = False
    whatsThis = None
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        if not self.installed:
            # ensure that only one instance of WhatsThisHelper is installed
            self.__class__.installed = True
            QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().installEventFilter(self)
            self.active = True

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if not obj.isWidgetType():
            return False
        if (event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress 
            and event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton
            and obj.whatsThis() and 
            obj.testAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_CustomWhatsThis)):
                self.whatsThis = SelectableWhatsThis(obj, event.globalPos())
                QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
                return True
        elif event.type() in (event.MouseButtonRelease, event.MouseButtonDblClick):
            if self.whatsThis:
                QtWidgets.QWhatsThis.leaveWhatsThisMode()
                return True
        elif event.type() == event.LeaveWhatsThisMode:
            QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().removeEventFilter(self)
            self.deleteLater()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def __del__(self):
        if self.active:
            self.__class__.installed = False


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.EnterWhatsThisMode:
            WhatsThisHelper(self)
        return super().event(event)
```

Note that you need to override the `event` of *all* widgets that are going to be top level widgets (all QMainWindows, QDialogs, etc) and need to support this.

Comment: thanks for the answer but is still the same problem ,so i can't select the text in whatsThis in my tab widget